# Enabling windows deployment services in Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

I have been trying to enable Windows Deployment Service in Windows Server 2008 R2 all to no avail.
I have been to many sites and tried different things but still, nothing works.

When I try to enable it, the following error comes up:
"Windows Deployment Services could not be started"

In the events log, two error messages and some info messages are displayed each time I try it.

The two error messages are:

> 1)Error id 513: "system32\wdsddps.dll. Windows Deployment Services
>   server will be shut down.      Error Information: 0x906".
>
> 2)Error id 257: "An error occurred while trying to start the Windows
>   Deployment Services server.     Error Information: 0x906".

I am trying to deploy an asp.net core application to the server from visual studio 2017.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: This question might be a better fit on https://serverfault.com.  There is an official tag for Windows Deployment Services there: https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/wds.  Currently with 329 questions.

Answer (score 0):

You can most likely fix this by unintializing the server and re-initializing it, which will recreate the share. From a command prompt, run:

```
wdsutil /uninitialize-server
wdsutil /initialize-server /reminst:[PATH_TO_REMOTEINSTALL_DIRECTORY]
```

More info 
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-]US/265b4b53-63ac-491f-817c-6030daa39b81/cant-start-windows-deployment-services-service?forum=itprovistadeployment

Comment: Says my computer is not currently joined to a domain. Sorry, I'm a rookie in server administration.

Comment: Have a look at this link it might help you https://serverfault.com/questions/193762/windows-deployment-services-without-a-domain

Answer (score 0):

So the problem was finally solved in the following steps:

1)The server had to be joined to an existing domain

2)Install Active Directory and DNS from the server roles

3)Install IIS

4)Install WDS

Hope this solves your problem as well.
Thanks to @Wojtek T for his reply. It helped.